# How to type property 'key' on Preact stateless component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

Here is the stateless component:

```
interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element;
  title: string;
  isHidden: boolean;
}

function TabContent({ children, title, isHidden }: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <section
      id={title}
      hidden={isHidden}
    >
      {children}
    </section>
  );
}

export default TabContent;
```

And I consume it in a `map` like so:

```
createTabContent = tabs => {
    return tabs.map((tab, id) => (
      <TabContent key={id} title={tab.title} isHidden={!(this.state.activeTab === id)}>
        {tab}
      </TabContent>
    ));
  };
```

But Typescript is complaining the `Property 'key' does not exist on type Props`.

I have looked into how to type a stateless component in React such as this [guide](https://medium.com/@ethan_ikt/react-stateless-functional-component-with-typescript-ce5043466011). They all require access to the `React` module but I'm using Preact..

Comment: I guess you could just add `key?: string | number` (or whatever type that makes sense) to the `Props`

Comment: Sure that works, but I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way?

Comment: Have you tried to use `FunctionComponent` or `ComponentType` from preact itself? https://github.com/developit/preact/blob/master/src/index.d.ts#L65

Comment: Oh. How do I use it though?

Comment: something like `const TabContent: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children, title, isHidden }) => ...`

Comment: I import like this `import { h, FunctionalComponent } from "preact";`. It works. Thank you!

Comment: I'll post as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preact has similar to React's components [typings](https://github.com/developit/preact/blob/master/src/index.d.ts). So you can use one of `ComponentType`, `FunctionComponent`, `FunctionalComponent`:

```
import { FunctionalComponent } from 'preact';

const TabContent: FunctionalComponent<Props> = ({ children, title, isHidden }) => (
    <section
        id={title}
        hidden={isHidden}
    >
        {children}
    </section>
);
```